# Firebase getValue() not functioning as expected

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

Error getValue() is not a function.
According to the documentation I've read `snapshot.getValue()` should return the value with out the key.

I do the following:

```
firebase.attendanceNotes(props.orgId, props.data.uid)
    .limitToLast(1)
    .once('value')
    .then(returnedNotes => {
      console.log(returnedNotes.getValue());
    })
```

This kicks out the error I mentioned above.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks like it's JavaScript.

`getValue()` is for Java. In JavaScript it's `val()`.